# Unable to automate gmail login using selenium, Asking to enter code after email id input

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am getting the following screen to enter code while login into my google account.

**Login to dropbox using gmail**
[image: Login to dropbox using gmail]

**Login to accounts.google.com**

[image: Login to accounts.google.com]

How can we eliminate this screen while automating this page. Do we have any other suggestion to automate this page.

Comment: Check for similar questions. You won;t solve this yourself. Ask developers for assistance.

Comment: try to reuse cookies for that

Comment: It is working when I run it in my local (Mac - chrome), It's not working when I run in Jenkins (windows) machine. Is there any way to change the settings to trust the sytem?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exactly purpose of this.
Google doesn’t want you to automate this process for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

This usesd to be able to be done through signing in at stackoverflow and redirecting to gmail account directly.  It seems like it is no longer supported in a session started by Selenium.